# RazorPages Crud IIS Application giving DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, ssms, razor-pages

I have been learning Asp.Net frameworks and while following [Razor Pages Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) i'm getting **`DbUpdateConcurrencyException`** exception on my IIS deployed application. I have tried using **[Exception Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/da1?view=aspnetcore-3.1#review-concurrency-exception-handling)** as suggested by the tutorial but i still get same exception. So what i'm doing here is while creating an object i get **`DbUpdateConcurrencyException`** but on Edit and Delete there's no exception. So i can't create any objects from CRUD app but can add from SQL Server Management Tool. Can someone help recognise where i'm going wrong?

As Suggested in exception traceback, it says `Create.Cshtml.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using RazorPagesMovie.Data;
using RazorPagesMovie.model;

namespace RazorPagesMovie.Pages.Movies
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly RazorPagesMovie.Data.RazorPagesMovieContext _context;

        public CreateModel(RazorPagesMovie.Data.RazorPagesMovieContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Movie Movie { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

             _context.Movie.Add(Movie);
             await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

`model/Movie.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RazorPagesMovie.model
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

}
```

`Create.cshtml`

```
@page
@model RazorPagesMovie.Pages.Movies.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Movie</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Movie.Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Movie.Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Movie.ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Movie.ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Movie.ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Movie.Genre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Movie.Genre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Genre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Movie.Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Movie.Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

[image: Here the error page]

Comment: you should add your Movie model, and the .cshtml file... seems like a primary key issue.  (Possibly has a UID/key in your form?)

Comment: Hi. If you look at the top of the tutorial, you'll find a link "View or download sample code". I suggest that you compare your code with the code on Github, that's part of the learning process :-)

Comment: Hi @Roar S. I've thoroughly compared the code between mine and https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start/sample/RazorPagesMovie30/Pages/Movies/Create.cshtml.cs  we'll they're same.

Comment: If the sample code doesn't run, you should notify Microsoft. I see a couple of small differences between the code on GitHub and your code. Have you tried to run the code from GitHub?

Comment: Please mention your reason for downvote.

Comment: the namespace could be wrong... What is the directory name that contains your models?  I think it should be "namespace RazorPagesMovie.[directory_name_here]"  (and first part is project name...)  Also, I don't think you need "using RazorPagesMovie.Data;" there... though not sure that would cause any problems.  You're already injecting the context which in this case is a db table...

Comment: btw, I've heard other people mention scaffolding problems in .net core 3.1.  You may want to just use .net core 2.2 instead, and re-scaffold.  It's obvious that the github of the tutorial pages is in a work in progress kind of state.  I also found this bug report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/822390/scaffolding-incorrect-namespace.html

Comment: I was using `datetime` in ssms table, whereas `datetime2` is supported as given in migration, changing the table column type did the trick, thanks everyone.